# Cannot boot Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, bootloader

So I boot up my computer after installing Ubuntu 13.04. Grub correctly shows me all available boot options and I am able to boot to Ubuntu. However, when I try to boot into Windows 7, grub hangs at a purple screen.

I have an HP laptop. It came with all four primary partitions taken up by the Windows bootloader, the actual Windows partition, one called `HP_TOOLS`, and another for HP Restore. I was able to back up and delete `HP_TOOLS` and the recovery partition, and change my disk type from Dynamic to Basic (GParted doesn't recognize Dynamic drives). I then booted into a live session of Ubuntu and made two partitions with GParted: one large partition for storage space that I could use between the two operating systems (`sda4`), and another extended partition (`sda3`) which contained Ubuntu (`sda6`) and it's swap space (`sda5`).

It currently looks like this:

[image: partitions]

I'm not sure if the second paragraph is actually relevant, I just want you to know all the variables in the equation.

Thank you in advance for helping this poor noob.

Comment: Have you tried with [this methods](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)?

Comment: How did you restore Windows partitions? And did you actually restore them?

Comment: You could try using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) which is explained pretty well in the thread Lucio mentioned. Alternatively since you are having trouble accessing the windows partition you could try a boot repair from a windows rescue CD but then you should be prepared for GRUB repair after that.

Comment: @Lucio I just did, with no prevail.

Comment: @Danatela I didn't restore any Windows partitions.

Comment: @DrA7 I used Boot Repair as you suggested and now grub loads Windows fine. However, Windows is stuck on the "Starting Windows" screen.

Comment: That means that Ubuntu and GRUB are *fine*. The problem is your Windows partitions.

Comment: I got Windows to boot up by restoring it's default bootloader. The problem now is getting my system to recognize grub. Anyway, that's a different problem, and this one has been solved. So, DrA7, if you want to make an answer out of your comment, I can accept it.

Comment: The problem was that I had tried Boot Repair before, but when it asked me if it could delete one of the partitions, I said no and nothing happened. This time however, I said yes. Problem solved.

Comment: You should create a new answer, telling how did you solve the problem, and mark it as accepted. So this question remains as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) which is explained pretty well in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows).

If you are also having trouble accessing the windows partition you could try a boot repair from a [Windows Rescue CD](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/create-a-system-repair-disc).

After using a Windows Rescue CD you will in all likelihood need to use Boot Repair to restore a GRUB menu.

Comment: +1 good answer, I have a question, does "Windows Rescue CD" image available for download anywhere? (My Sony VAIO had preinstalled Win8, and there is no CD. The laptop vendor had provided 4 recovery disks, which I lost.) I have even put a [thread for bounty](http://askubuntu.com/questions/330015/ubuntu-13-04-and-windows-8-dual-boot-problem-where-windows-8-doesnt-boot), see if you can help me.

Comment: A quick google query lead me to [this](http://www.windowsreinstall.com/winre/createfromiso/#Downloads) though I can not vouch for the sites legality nor quality.

Comment: But I am anyway getting the recovery environment without this CD/DVD. With which we can perform repair or open command prompt (though everything I have tried and no luck). Do you think inserting a CD/DVD for repairing will add value? If yes, then I will give it a try.

Comment: I do not know if there is any difference between the CD or the on-drive recovery, wouldn't hurt to try though.